# How to change file name in QLPreviewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have saved a normal ".txt" file with a customized file name. While displaying this file in QLPreviewController and tapping "Mail" option, the attached file name is same as that i have given while saving it. I want to change the name of the file while displaying in "MAIL".
Is it possible to do so?
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the other way round: save under the name you want to appear in Mail.app and customize name in QLPreviewController by implementing:

```
- (id)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)idx
```

and customizing `QLPreviewItem` returned from it (`previewItemTitle`).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need..

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.yourFilePath]
                               mimeType:@"application/txt" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MAIL.txt"]];
```